# Binding IsSelected on ListViewItem not working for me in UWP application

Tags: xaml, listview, uwp, listviewitem

I'm working with a list of objects that have a `Selected` property and I'm trying to bind it to the `IsSelected` property on `ListViewItem` within a multi-select `ListView` control in UWP.

I just can't seem to get the binding to work. The checkboxes in the `ListView` do not render checked if `Selected = True` and the Set on `Selected` never gets triggered when checking an item.

[image]

SettingsPage.xaml

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="PreviewColumnTemplate" x:DataType="models:Column">
        <TextBlock>
            <Run Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
            <Run Text=" ("/>
            <Run Text="{x:Bind ColumnValidation.column_label}"/>
            <Run Text=") "/>
        </TextBlock>
    </DataTemplate>

    <Style x:Key="previewColumnListViewItem" TargetType="ListViewItem">
        
    </Style>
</Page.Resources>
        
<ListView
    x:Name="previewColumnListView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentDrillHole.Collar.Columns, Mode=TwoWay}"
    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource PreviewColumnTemplate}"
    Height="400"
    SelectionMode="Multiple"
    SelectionChanged="previewColumnListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" BasedOn="{StaticResource previewColumnListViewItem}">
            <Setter Property="IsSelected" Value="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
        </Style>
    </ListView.Resources>
</ListView>
```

The `ViewModel.CurrentDrillHole.Collar` object is of type `Table` and looks like so:

```
public class Table : BindableBase
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TableValidation TableValidation { get; set; }
    public List<Column> Columns { get; set; }
    public List<Row> Rows { get; set; } = new List<Row>();
}
```

And the `Column` object looks like so. It is here I want to bind to the `Selected` property.

```
public class Column : BindableBase, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public ColumnValidation ColumnValidation { get; set; }
    public List<RefEntryValue> LookupValues { get; set; } = null;

    private bool _selected = false;

    public bool Selected {
        get => _selected;

        set
        {
            _selected = value;

            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

Any ideas of things I can try would be greatly appreciated. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you set SelectionMode="Multiple", ListViewItem uses the default ListViewItemTemplate whose key is "ListViewItemExpanded".

Its style is as follows:

```
 <Style TargetType="ListViewItem" x:Key="ListViewItemExpanded">
    ......
    <ControlTemplate TargetType="ListViewItem">
        <Grid x:Name="ContentBorder"
          Control.IsTemplateFocusTarget="True"
          FocusVisualMargin="{TemplateBinding FocusVisualMargin}"
          Background="{TemplateBinding Background}"
          BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}"
          BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}"
          CornerRadius="{TemplateBinding CornerRadius}"
          RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            ……
            <Border x:Name="MultiSelectSquare"
                        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        Width="20"
                        Height="20"
                        Margin="12,0,0,0"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Visibility="Collapsed">
                <Border.Clip>
                    <RectangleGeometry Rect="0,0,20,20">
                        <RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                            <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectClipTransform" />
                        </RectangleGeometry.Transform>
                    </RectangleGeometry>
                </Border.Clip>
                <Border.RenderTransform>
                    <TranslateTransform x:Name="MultiSelectCheckBoxTransform" />
                </Border.RenderTransform>
                <FontIcon x:Name="MultiSelectCheck"
                            FontFamily="{ThemeResource SymbolThemeFontFamily}"
                            Glyph="&#xE73E;"
                            FontSize="16"
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemControlForegroundBaseMediumHighBrush}"
                            Visibility="Collapsed"
                            Opacity="0" />
            </Border>
            <Border x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayTextBorder"
                        Opacity="0"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Margin="12,0,0,0"
                        MinWidth="20"
                        Height="20"
                        VerticalAlignment="Center"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                        Background="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundAccentBrush}"
                        BorderThickness="2"
                        BorderBrush="{ThemeResource SystemControlBackgroundChromeWhiteBrush}">
                <TextBlock x:Name="MultiArrangeOverlayText"
              Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=TemplateSettings.DragItemsCount}"
              Style="{ThemeResource CaptionTextBlockStyle}"
              IsHitTestVisible="False"
              Opacity="0"
              VerticalAlignment="Center"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              AutomationProperties.AccessibilityView="Raw" />
            </Border>

        </Grid>

    </ControlTemplate>
    </Setter.Value>
</Style>
```

As you can see, there is no CheckBox in its style, it is composed by Border and FontIcon.

If you want to solve this problem, I suggest that you could add CheckBox to DataTemplate. By doing this, we can bind “Selected’ to the “IsChecked” property of the CheckBox.
Please refer to the following code.

```
<ListView
x:Name="previewColumnListView"
ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentDrillHole.Collar.Columns, Mode=TwoWay}"   
Height="400"
SelectionChanged="previewColumnListView_SelectionChanged">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:Key="PreviewColumnTemplate" x:DataType="models:Column">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock>
          <Run Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
          <Run Text=" ("/>
          <Run Text="{x:Bind ColumnValidation.column_label}"/>
          <Run Text=") "/>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Comment: This is indeed the answer.

**SettingsPage.xaml**

Answer (score 0):

This is how it ended up looking in the end. Does this seem clunky to anyone else? It would be nice if the ListView control made it easier to deal with collections and `SelectionMode="Multiple"`.

**SettingsPage.xaml**

```
<ListView
    x:Name="previewColumnListView"
    ItemsSource="{x:Bind ViewModel.CurrentDrillHole.Collar.Columns, Mode=TwoWay}"
    Height="400"
    SelectionChanged="previewColumnListView_SelectionChanged"
    IsItemClickEnabled="True"
    ItemClick="previewColumnListView_ItemClick">
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate x:DataType="models:Column">
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <CheckBox Click="previewColumnListView_CheckBox_Click" IsChecked="{Binding Selected, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                <TextBlock>
                  <Run Text="{x:Bind name}"/>
                  <Run Text=" ("/>
                  <Run Text="{x:Bind ColumnValidation.column_label}"/>
                  <Run Text=") "/>
                </TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

**SettingsPage.xaml.cs**

```
private async void previewColumnListView_CheckBox_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    // update the list of selected columns
    Settings.CollarPreviewFields = ViewModel.CurrentDrillHole.Collar.Columns.Where(x => x.Selected).Select(x => x.name).ToList();

    await App.SaveSettings();
}

private void previewColumnListView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{
    Column selectedColumn = (Column)e.ClickedItem;

    selectedColumn.Selected = !selectedColumn.Selected;

    // trigger checkbox click event. will update the list and save.
    previewColumnListView_CheckBox_Click(null, null);
}
```

[image]